# How to force member functions of class templates to be instantiated?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I have recently found out that the member functions of class templates aren't instantiated until they're used, which is extremely annoying because it makes certain SFINAE constructs not work. I would like to know how to make sure that a member function of a class template specialization is always instantiated as soon as the class is instantiated -- but only using statements inside the class template definition, so that if the member function could not be instantiated, SFINAE kicks in and the compiler falls back on the general class template.

The code I was planning to use looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class test_type {
    // general template; dummy parameter U is to allow specialization.
    static const bool value = false;
}

template <typename T>
class test_type<T, T> {
    // template specialization
    void f(T t) {
        // do all sorts of type-specific operations with t
        // (e.g., calling member functions)

        // if T is not suitable for these operations, I want
        // a substitution error to be generated so that the
        // general template is used instead
    }

    static const bool value = true;
}

template <typename T>
using satisfies = test_type<T, T>::value;
```

Comment: What SFINAE constructs? The ones I know depend on the declaration of those member functions, which *are* instantiated when the class is.

Comment: Some code of what you're trying to do will be useful.

Comment: @StoryTeller There's a general class template whose static `value` member is false, but there's a template specialization whose `value` member is true, but which also includes a member function that does a whole bunch of operations on template parameter T. The idea being, if type T is suitable for the operations performed by the member function, then the `value` member will evaluate to true. Otherwise, the specialization will fail to instantiate, the compiler will fall back on the general template, and `value` will be false. Problem is the compiler doesn't even try to instantiate the function.

Comment: SFINAE works on declaration, the definition is not really needed...

Comment: Less descriptions and more code.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `enable_if` the specialization? As the author of the class you know all the constraints on T...

Comment: @Anonymous1847 - I don't follow. If the `value` alone is not enough to tell that `f` can be called and be well formed when instantiated, you have a bug in your library. Force instantiating an ill-formed `f` will not cause a silent substitution failure in a SFINAE context, it will be a hard error.

Comment: I've added code to the question. @jrok Well, to use enable_if, I would have to have a type trait class like is_scalar, which is precisely what I'm trying to write already... @ StoryTeller f() has no purpose besides to cause a substitution failure when T is not suitable. I'm asking for a way to tell the compiler to attempt to instantiate f() when it attempts to instantiate test_type, instead of delaying it until f() is used, at which point it has already left the SFINAE context.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 As StoryTeller already said, you don't get substitution failure (in the "not an error" sense) if the function _body_ fails to compile with the given substitutions. SFINAE works only on substitutions in the signature!

Comment: @Anonymous1847 So the problem is you don't have a suitable type trait class?

Comment: Checking for possible operations with a type trait can often be done by combining `void_t` and `decltype`.

Answer (score 5):

The body of the member functions in a class will not be a part of SFINAE. The template gets instantiated depending on the signature, and once the class has been instantiated a faulty member function will lead to a hard error.

What you need to do is build a type_trait that you can place in the template specialization. Here's a toy example that checks for two different member functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using check_for_method = std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().run()), decltype(std::declval<T>().go())>;

template <typename T, typename U = void>
class test_type {
public:
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
class test_type<T, check_for_method<T>> {
public:
    void f(T t) {
        t.run();
        t.go();
    }

    static const bool value = true;
};

struct Foo {
    void run() {
        std::cout << "Running\n";
    }
};

struct Bar : Foo {
    void go() {
        std::cout << "Going\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    test_type<Foo> t1;
    test_type<int> t2;
    test_type<Bar> t3;

    std::cout << t1.value << " " << t2.value << " " << t3.value << std::endl;
    t3.f(Bar{});
}
```